# Cron python job not running

Tags: python-3, cron

I tried to automate the launch of a python script.
After having tested it works in thonny, I moved to Cron and I got quite lost.

I started from calling `12 21 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/main.py`
to `12 21 * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/pi/main.py`(with minute and hour value to change accordingly to the time of test) but nothing happens.

I ultimately tried to add the following line: `12 21 * * * (echo "hi" >>/var/log/it_runs.txt)`
and that indeed print an "hi" in a "it_runs" txt file.
That makes me think the problem is with calling python.
Do I call python in the wrong way? When debugging with Thonny i set python as 3.5.

Pls and advice is more than accepted
Ale

Comment: There could be lots of reasons. But since you already know how to log console output from a cronjob, why not do the same for your main.py script and see what the log tells you ?

Comment: I tried again many times today. I found out that it runs smoothly when on terminal

Comment: What happens when you run `/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/main.py` from your CLI (the terminal)?

Comment: It runs smoothly

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell us what your Python script did - or was supposed to do. We try to answer RPi-related questions here, but all of our mind-readers are currently on strike for better wages. So you're left to depend on people like me who need some information to provide answers.

All that said, I'm going to take a guess. I'll answer your question in this way - by a working example that is as similar to yours as I know how to make it:

1. Create a Python script in user pi's home directory;

   ```bsh
   $ nano hello.py
   ```
2. Enter a single line in the editor:

   ```
   print("Hello from Python Script Launched run under cron")
   ```
3. Save & close the editor - check to ensure the file `/home/pi/hello.py` exists
4. Open your `crontab` for editing:

   ```bsh
   $ crontab -e
   ```
5. Make the following entry at the bottom of your `crontab`:

   ```
   * * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/hello.py >> hellopy.txt 2>&1
   ```
6. Save & exit the `crontab` editor - it should confirm that a new `crontab` has been installed
7. You can see the once-per-minute output as it goes to the output file using `tail`:

   ```bsh
   $ $ tail -f -n 10 hellopy.txt
   Hello from Python Script Launched run under cron
   Hello from Python Script Launched run under cron
   etc, etc, etc
   ```

   <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to end the listing (or just use `cat` instead of `tail` if you prefer)

---

#### EDIT/ADDENDUM:

To view your user environment:

```bsh
$ printenv
```

To view your "cron user's environment", add the following line to your crontab:

> @reboot sleep 10; /usr/bin/printenv > /home/pi/cronenv.txt 2>&1

Review the differences between these two environments in light of your Python program.

Comment: Dear Seamus, thank you for your answer.

My python script is supposed to get rain precipitation data from a certain region and post a tweet. 
Indeed, it works when launching the script from terminal.

but nothing happens when using cron.

Comment: @mant0: Have you tried the steps I outlined in the answer?

Comment: yes, but without any improvement:(

Comment: @mant0: I don't see how to help you without more information on your Python script and your `crontab` listing. It's clear that the "approach" is sound and correct. ... As another ***guess***, could it be that when you run this script from the terminal it prompts you for input? Or perhaps it is using resources or environment variables that aren't available to `cron`? I understand you're not deliberately withholding information, but you need to understand that you've not given us enough to do anything more than **guess** at the problem - and I hate guessing.

Comment: I do understand your point of view.
However, de facto, I am trying all I can with no solution.
After installing the new OS on raspberry pi, I re-install every lib i had in the past.
Again, the same problem occur. I can run the very same command from terminal and it runs smoothly.
Funny thing, using any other python script is fine.

Comment: @mant0: I don't make guarantees... BUT - If your script runs from the CLI, and it does not run under `cron`, then this is due to a difference in your ***environment***. You seem reluctant to post any code, or provide results of your troubleshooting efforts. That's your business of course - I'm not trying to coerce anything. However, you may wish to consider reviewing or providing the output of your environment, and your `cron` environment. See the recent edit to my answer. As a quick afterthought to this - how are you handling your Twitter authentication??

Comment: I will post the output for the environment tomorrow. I am away for work, haven't had time for the project recently.
The code is part of a personal project for raising awareness for the lack of rain precipitation. It should tweet, everyday, the cumulative precipitation comparison between the current year and the same day of 10 years ago in a specific region. I can share the code if you wish, just avoided to do so since it runs from terminal.
With respect to Twitter, I use Twitter api and tweepy, it is a simple process. If you wish I can share some link with you.
Thank you, again :)

Comment: @mant0: Perhaps you should compare the two environments before adding a lot of details to your OP?

Comment: do you mean like printing sys.path?

Comment: @mant0: No - I meant what I said in the `EDIT/ADDENDUM` to my answer. Your Python script runs fine when you invoke it from your **interactive `bash` shell** - ***correct??***  So compare **that** environment to `cron` environment by running `printenv` as a `cron` job. The Edit/Addendum shows how to get both environments. Then, compare the two... does anything *stand out*? - is anything *missing* from `cron`'s environment that you think may be necessary?